# Is Categorical Crossentropy Loss always bounded in the [0, 1] interval?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, loss-function

Is Categorical Crossentropy always bounded between 0 and 1, or is it possible that during training of a Neural Network it can get higher values?

More specifically, I'm referring to the [TensorFlow 2.0 function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy).

Answer (score 5):

You can actually get values from $[0, \infty[$. Consider the cross entropy loss be following formula:

$loss (y_{pred}, y_{true}) = - \log{y_{pred, class_i}}$

, whereas the index $class_i$ states that you only use the output of the $i$th class.

For example think that your true class is $dog$, which is represented by the $3$rd output neuron. On the $3$rd output neuron your network outputs a probability of $10\%$. Your loss is then $-\log{10\%}= 2.3$. Further if your probability is only $0.1\%$ your loss will equal $6.9$ and so on.

Remember that:

$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}{\log{x}} = -\infty$